# Error in Email Program in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, email, smtplib

I started with a very simple email program in python where I am trying to send an message from my GMail address. I am always getting the error below,

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\BarmanJa\Documents\PythonfromShell\TT\infi.py", line 15, in <module>
>     server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
>   File "C:\Users\BarmanJa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 251, in __init__
>     (code, msg) = self.connect(host, port)
>   File "C:\Users\BarmanJa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 336, in connect
>     self.sock = self._get_socket(host, port, self.timeout)
>   File "C:\Users\BarmanJa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 307, in _get_socket
>     self.source_address)
>   File "C:\Users\BarmanJa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 724, in create_connection
>     raise err
>   File "C:\Users\BarmanJa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\socket.py", line 713, in create_connection
>     sock.connect(sa)
> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
> ```

I have tried all possible ways to correct it. I went through all the similar problems others had posted in the community but no change. Below is the original code

```
import smtplib

mailfrom = 'jayantamgr@gmail.com'
msg = 'Hello'

mailto = ('myname@yahoo.com')
username = 'hisname@gmail.com'
password = 'wwwwwwwwww'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
server.ehlo()
s.starttls()
server.login(username, password)

server.sendmail(mailfrom, mailto , msg)
server.quit()
```

Comment: I've edited your question to be more readable. However, you should [edit] it to include what you have actually tried – and the different traceback/error message. Otherwise, answerers could be wasting their time by suggesting ideas that you’ve already tried. Stating *I have tried all possible ways to correct it* actually implies it’s not possible to fix this. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that you can’t connect to the target machine (`smtp.gmail.com`):

> ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

I would suspect that you have some sort of firewall or anti-virus that blocks connections to the SMTP Submission Port as both the specified hostname (`smtp.gmail.com`) and port number are correct (587).

---

There’s also an (unrelated) error in your code: `s.starttls()` should be `server.starttls()`.

Comment: Is there anyway I would be able to work around the firewall or anti-virus that is blocking the connection? I am also facing the same issue.